# How to create a file with the current date appended in a SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have created an SSIS package and almost have it completed.

I am to the point where I'm trying to take the data that I've put into an Excel file and copy the file and rename it at the same time.

Basically, I have a file `InboundScrapWeights.xlsx` that I am copying to its final resting place. This location has a lot of other files that have the same name, but with the date they were created on the end so that they look like this: `InboundScrapWeights_20180216.xlsx`.

I've got a `File System Task` that is copying the file, but I cannot see how to append the date to the end of the file name. How do I get the date on there?

Comment: Your google search string is `ssis dynamic file name`.

Comment: @DanBracuk That helped with creating the variables that I needed for the answer that was provided to me below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- string variable fname
- string variable strDate

expressions:

fname

```
"InboundScrapWeights_" + @strDate + ".xlsx"
```

strDate

```
(DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yyyy" , GETDATE())
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2)
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2)
```

In FileTask destination is variable = true

set variable to fName (you proably need full path)